# Why does this BigInteger display incorrect results when entering FFFFFFFF (8 F)

Tags: java, hex, decimal, biginteger

I wanna use this code to achieve hexadecimal to decimal. When I enter FFFFFFFF(8F), it display 2415919102.However, 4294967295 is correct. And when I enter F or F or FFF...FFFFFFF(7F), it performs well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String t = in.next();
    in.close();

    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("0");
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=t.length()-1;i>=0;i--,j++) {
        char c = t.charAt(i);
        double val = Integer.valueOf(c+"",16);
        val = val*Math.pow(16, j);
        BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger((int)val+"");
        bi = bi.add(bi2);           
    }
    System.out.println(bi.toString());
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger` has a constructor that accepts a `String` and a radix.

Comment: During your debugging, add some more print statements. Tell us what the value of `(int)val` is at every step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Savior said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683579/why-does-this-biginteger-display-incorrect-results-when-entering-ffffffff-8-f#comment96155678_54683579):

```
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(t, 16);
```

> 4294967295

**What went wrong?**

You’re overflowing an `int` in this line:

```
        BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger((int)val+"");
```

When processing the leading `F` in an 8 digit hex number, your `double` is 4.02653184E9 or 4026531840.0, but is converted to the largest possible `int` value, which is only 2147483647. So your code works for strings that fit in `int`, up to `7FFFFFFF`, but gives incorrect results beyond that.